# jQuery smooth scrolling anchor URL issue

Tags: jquery

I have found a piece of code from CSS-Tricks which works well but I have a unique situation that requires some custom coding.

The original script:

```
$(function() {
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
&& location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
});
});
```

The problem I face is I use a CMS system.
The URL for a page what you see is:
http://www.sitename.com/home

The actual path to the page is:
http://www.sitename.com/home/index

The HTML looks like:

```
<a href="#one"></a>
<div id="one"></div>
```

What the CMS converts it to:

```
<a href="home/index#one"></a>
<div id="one"></div>
```

So the first time I click an anchor link instead of scrolling it jumps because it changes URL from /home to /home/index#one 
After that the smooth scroll works because now the URL is /home/index

Is there a way I can scroll between two elements without using anchors or without changing the URL or can the script from CSS-Tricks be altered for my unique situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this in a few ways. Here's a couple of options.

Simple answer is you could use HTML5 [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to push `/home/index`, into history, and onto the browsers URL, on load.

```
history.pushState({}, "index", "/home/index");
// or
history.replaceState({}, "index", "/home/index");
```

`.replaceState` would probably yield better UX, as it would avoid double-backs.

The other way is to rework how your anchors work. Using common classes, `data` attributes, and managing hashes on your own. We can avoid relying on our `href` to match our element's `id`. In this instance, `href` simply provides a fallback for when JS is turned off, and we set `id` attributes.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/fetuv/edit?html,js,output)</kbd> <kbd>[**OUTPUT**](http://output.jsbin.com/fetuv)</kbd>

See the output above for the best example.

```js
function setHash (h) {
  window.location.hash = h;
}

$('.section-link').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var self = $(this),
      target = self.data('target'),
      subject = $('[data-section-name="' + target + '"]'),
      offset = subject.offset().top;
  
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: offset
  }, 500);
  
  setHash(target);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  background-color: #eee;
}

section:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<section data-section-name="one">
    <h1>One</h1>
    
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#one" class="section-link" data-target="one">One</a>
        <a href="#two" class="section-link" data-target="two">Two</a>
        <a href="#three" class="section-link" data-target="three">Three</a>
        <a href="#four" class="section-link" data-target="four">Four</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section data-section-name="two">
    <h1>Two</h1>
    
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#one" class="section-link" data-target="one">One</a>
        <a href="#two" class="section-link" data-target="two">Two</a>
        <a href="#three" class="section-link" data-target="three">Three</a>
        <a href="#four" class="section-link" data-target="four">Four</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section data-section-name="three">
    <h1>Three</h1>
    
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#one" class="section-link" data-target="one">One</a>
        <a href="#two" class="section-link" data-target="two">Two</a>
        <a href="#three" class="section-link" data-target="three">Three</a>
        <a href="#four" class="section-link" data-target="four">Four</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section data-section-name="four">
    <h1>Four</h1>
    
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#one" class="section-link" data-target="one">One</a>
        <a href="#two" class="section-link" data-target="two">Two</a>
        <a href="#three" class="section-link" data-target="three">Three</a>
        <a href="#four" class="section-link" data-target="four">Four</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is amazing, what ever you do for a job you need a raise :) thanks!